# Installing XAMPP on MAC however is Apache not working I tried Changing the port to 85 Ask

Tags: php, apache

After a long time going through stack overflow trying different ways to solve this issue I decided to ask the question and show my steps, Story Short: 1. Now I have installed Xampp however Apache is not working? Please see image: 
[Showing its works in localhost/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTl7H.png)

And the Xampp is showing the following even after changing the port:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5SGZ.png)

and the ports are as follows: Port 80 SSL 443

Now I have changed the port to other numbers and still apache is not working, Can you please help in this matter. As I am trying to install cakephp after this.

Solutions already tried:

1. I changed the port to 85 from the config file http.config however it still didn't work, The picture showing its working appears even If i delete Xampp maybe that is due to mac preinstalled apache and php.
2. I stopped and Deleted Skype and teamspeak before installing Xampp . This has been done and still Apache doesn't work.
3. I have Changed the ports from the httpd.config

   Changed #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
   Listen 80

To :

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:85
Listen 85
```

However the SSL port Xampp does not let me change it. even if I used localhost:85/dashboard/ < Apache still gives me a red light doesnt work and the page doesnt work.

4. Someone suggested to check if there is a directory inside htdocs I checked and there is a directory called dashboard.
5. Someone from stackoverflow suggested (your localhost is working?? so where is the problm?)

Thats what I couldnt understand as when opening localhost/dashboard shows me this error

> localhost/dashboard :Not Found The requested URL /dashboard/ was not
>   found on this server.

Comment: why did you change the port to 85?

Comment: Trying to use a different port as an answer in stackoverflow suggested, But the effect was still apache is not working, so now I returned everything back to what it was. and posted this questions 
thanks

Comment: Then why did you not try to open link to that port? `http://localhost:85/dashboard/`

Comment: I tried it did not work i got a blank page and still apache in Xampp is not working. I amusing mac by the way

Comment: If you got a blank page, instead of "Not Found", it would indicate that webserver is working, but there was error in your PHP code ... and your default config for some reason has bee set to hide errors.

Comment: I uninstalled Xampp and reinstalled in Xampp again, I have not edited anything in the config file since, However befor installng xampp i updated PHP from this website https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/ to php 7, i check "php -v"... it gives me version 5 . Still nothing changed in apache still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using MAMP instead of Xampp, and was able to run apache,

MAMP uses port 8888